# SQL - INSERT IF NOT EXISTS based on COUNT

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to write an `INSERT` statement such that if a value in a column does not exist OR the `COUNT` of said value exists for less (<) than a certain number of rows the new data will be inserted (if the `COUNT` of the value is greater than or equal to said number nothing happens).

This SQL solves the first criteria, but not the second...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE day_count_table (day1 DATE, col1 STRING);
INSERT INTO day_count_table VALUES ('2022-04-01','Testing April 1, 2022');
INSERT INTO day_count_table VALUES ('2022-04-02','Testing April 2, 2022');
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE day_count_table_temp (day1 DATE, col1 STRING);
INSERT INTO day_count_table_temp VALUES ('2022-04-03','Testing April 3, 2022');

-- This works for the first criteria, but not sure how to incorporate the COUNT criteria
INSERT INTO day_count_table
SELECT * FROM day_count_table_temp a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM day_count_table b WHERE b.day1 = a.day1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your WHERE to:

```
WHERE 5 > (SELECT count(*) FROM day_count_table b WHERE b.day1 = a.day1);
```

Where 5 is the number you want to be less than - wouldn't that catch both circumstances... ie:  If there's no rows, count(*) would be 0, if there are fewer than your limit, you're good to.

Comment: That worked.  Seems pretty straight forward.  Are there edge cases to be concerned about?

Comment: Not that I can think of off hand.